# Where is the documentation of ARM / Terraform for Azure Synapse Pipeline, Spark Job Definition etc

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-synapse

I want to deploy a Synapse pipeline which contains a Spark Job definition, activities etc. with an terraform script or an ARM template. But i don't find any documentation for this. I found for data factory pipeline : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_pipeline but not equivalent documentation for Synapse.

Same issue with ARM documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/templates/).

I don't want to use the Workspace of Azure Synapse.

Is the documentation available ?

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you gone through this already .
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/quickstart-deployment-template-workspaces

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm looking for the doc of the arm template for synapse components such as the pipeline or spark job definition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this documentation exist (after some Microsoft Docs scouting).

You can create the pipelines and spark job definition in the Workspace and then click on the 'Publish'-button. If you have GIT-integration, this will generate an ARM Template in your GIT repo under the branch 'workspace_publish' (default value). With this ARM you can see how Synapse Workspace creates the ARM for pipelines and spark job definitions and then reuse the same pattern/syntax.